# CSV file using mixture of date formats

Tags: csv, datetime, formatting, date-format, date-formatting

I've been producing a csv file from Salesforce Marketing Cloud. The date column is using two different date formats for seemingly random dates:

[image]

How can I stop it from doing this? I have also exported it from SFMC in a text format, and all the dates are in the same format in that file, but as soon as I convert it to CSV it puts them in this variety of formats. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think that is just Excel fixing them up for you (which is messing them up). You said that it looks on in the actual file, maybe select the UpdateDate columns and force a date format on the whole column.

Answer (score 1):

Excel tries to fix it for you. You should import into excel using the' Data Tab > Get External Data'. As you import make sure you select the correct date format for the column with your dates. ie MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss AM/PM.